# Undefined symbol error with -static-libasan

Tags: c++, soci, address-sanitizer

I use address sanitizer to sanitize  my application,  Which is linked with SOCI. But that prompt followijg error message while using with Oracle.

```
./SociUT: symbol lookup error: /home/testhome/libs/libsoci_oracle.d.so.1.4.18: undefined symbol: __asan_unregister_globals
```

Here is the build output of aplication

```
/home/rel/GCC/asan-gcc-4.9.3/bc0232/bin/g++ -std=c++11  -g3 -static-libasan -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -L/home/mt_1/4/4.7.c/build/bc0397/tech/MB/link/API/63  -L/usr/lib64  -L/usr/lib64  -L/home/janaka077/mt-git/mt-database/mt_1/database_SOCI_Core/bin  -L/usr/local/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib  -L/usr/local/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib  -L/usr/local/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs   -o SociUT Main.o version.o  -lmb.d -lrdmacm -libverbs -lxml2 -lmsoci.d -lboost_date_time -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_serializion -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lgtest -lz  -lnsl -lrt -ldl -lz -lcrypt -lnuma
```

Answer (score 5):

This is [GCC PR 64234](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64234). At some point I may even get to fixing it)

Can you use dynamic runtime instead (i.e. remove `-static-libasan`)? Another option is adding `-lsoci_oracle.d` to `LDFLAGS` (this would inform GCC to export necessary symbols). Or you can add a really silly workaround: force a reference to missing symbol from your code:

```
extern "C" void __asan_unregister_globals();
extern "C" void __asan_register_globals();
__attribute__((used)) void *force_missing_symbols[] = {
  (void *)__asan_unregister_globals,
  (void *)__asan_register_globals
};
```

(you'll need to do this for *all* missing symbols).

Comment: What are the LDFLAGS ?

Comment: @Janaka: Linker flags.

Comment: In this case, I need to keep my application independent from Oracle.  So that won't be good solution for me.

Comment: @Janaka: I added an (ugly) workaround. Or you can ask GCC maintainers to fix this by posting a comment in Bugzilla.

Comment: @Janaka: Did you have a chance to try suggested workarounds?