# Address Sanitizer on a python extension

Tags: python, clang, address-sanitizer

I am trying to compile a python extension with Address Sanitizer. When I load the extension, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from extension import package
  File "/tmp/python_test/extension/package.py", line 28, in <module>
    from extension._ext import *
ImportError: /tmp/python_test/extension/_ext.so: undefined symbol: __asan_version_mismatch_check_v8
```

The compiler invocation is

```
clang -g -o _ext.so code.ll -fsanitize=address -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -fPIC -shared
```

So, it does not load symbols from asan correctly. I've tried using `-static-libsan`, but the result was the same.

I've seen that some people use `LD_PRELOAD` to get Asan into shared objects, however, it seems that the `libasan.so` on my system is from a different version of Address Sanitizer (Installed from Debian's libasan3 package, while I got clang from deb http://apt.llvm.org/stretch/ llvm-toolchain-stretch-8 main).

So, how can I make Address Sanitizer work with a shared object library? 
Either, I need the correct version of `libasan.so` (which does not seem to be in deb http://apt.llvm.org/stretch/ llvm-toolchain-stretch-8 main, or I need a way to have clang link that statically).

My clang version:

```
$ clang -v
clang version 8.0.0-svn356034-1~exp1~20190313094216.53 (branches/release_80)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To sanitize a single library (without sanitizing main `python` executable) with Clang you should

- add `-shared-libasan` to `LDFLAGS` (Clang defaults to `-static-libasan`, unlike GCC)
- run with `LD_PRELOAD=$(clang -print-file-name=libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so)` (it should be somewhere with standard Clang libs)

(see [AddressSanitizerAsDso wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAsDso)).

Another option is using GCC, in which case `-shared-libasan` is not needed and `LD_PRELOAD` value becomes `libasan.so.N` (`N` depends on GCC version, use `$(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)` to locate it).

For more details on differences between GCC and Clang with respect to sanitization of shlibs see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022141/2170527).

Comment: It works. The correct file name is /usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so.

Comment: @Alex Check my update, we can identify library location automagically.

Comment: For Mac users: Use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` instead of `LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: @StuartBerg Thanks! Would you mind adding this to answer?