Unable to debug python C extension using valgrind
I am trying to debug a C extension I made using CFFI. I am using Python 3.11 and Valgrind 3.18.1.
As far as I can tell from the docs the only setup needed is setting the PYTHONMALLOC=malloc environment variable, but for some reason, valgrind just refuses to report any errors with or without it being set.
For example:
# test.py
from myproj._myproj import lib, ffi

handle = ffi.new("MyType_t **")

# Call malloc to allocate some space on the heap and return a pointer to it
lib.func_that_calls_malloc(handle)

# Deallocate the data pointed to by the handle
# Oh no! I forgot to call this function. This will result in a memory leak!
# lib.func_that_frees_the_handle(handle)

# del handle # CFFI manages the handle itself, so it is unnecessary to deallocate it manually.

$ PYTHONMALLOC=malloc valgrind --show-leak-kinds=definite --leak-check=full  python test.py
==2880771== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2880771== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2880771== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2880771== Command: /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python test.py
==2880771== 
$ valgrind --show-leak-kinds=definite --leak-check=full  python test.py
==2881962== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2881962== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2881962== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2881962== Command: /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python test.py
==2881962== 

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT:
I should have mentioned this before - I am not trying to debug the CFFI extension itself. The CFFI wrapper code is autogenerated and the underlying C library that I am writing has its own tests. I am trying to test that my usage of the C extension in Python does not cause memory leaks. I have modified the python code example above to better illustrate this.

Try using the C compiler sanitizer instead of valgrind. It can spot buffer overflows and other corruptions when/where they occur. They are mutually exclusive as they both need to hook malloc. Compile with -Wall -O0 -g -fsanitize=address,undefined

What is wrong with your C extension, specifically? What behavior is happening that you are trying to debug? Please edit your question and post your C code

@CraigEstey just building the lib with asan isn't enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692357/address-sanitizer-on-a-python-extension

@CraigEstey  I have modified my question to better showcase what I want to achieve. Bottom line is I need valgrind to show me heap allocs/frees.

Most likely your process is doing a fork/exec.
If you do that with the default Valgrind options the exec'd process won't be running under Valgrind.
Use the --trace-children=yes option.

Wow that worked, but now I have the opposite problem - it is showing a lot of errors even when I run it like so PYTHONMALLOC=malloc valgrind --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full  python -c "" - i.e without any actual python code. Is there a way to suppress this and make it only report errors happening inside certain python files or related to the C ext  usage?

I tried using the suppression file but that didn't help. I still see lots of errors.

To clarify further:
I uncommented the lines for _PyObject_Free and _PyObject_Realloc suppressions. I am also running a debug version of Python (compiled via pyenv install 3.11.0 --debug). I can see that python has been compiled with -g -00 when I run python -m sysconfig | grep CFLAGS.
None of this seems to help.

Without seeing the errors I can't tell much. If you want a "baseline" suppressions file you can use --gen-suppressions=all and generate a suppression file from the output.
